# Comparing Lists elements and sets in python

Tags: python

First I'll show my code and then I'll explain:

```
for eachfile in matches:
    if eachfile in set1:
        print 'find one match'
        shutil.copy2(eachfile, '/Users/r2-d2/Desktop/folder')
        print 'copy done'
```

`matches` is a list like this:

```
[fooFILE_Aspam.txt, barFILE_B.CSV, codeFILE_Cdog.vcf]
```

`set1` is a set like which looks like this:

```
(FILE_A, FILE_B, FILE_F...)
```

I'm iterating over the list to check if inside each entry there's any of the elements of the set. If it does I copy the entry away.
In the above example scenario I expect a match for `FILE_A` and `FILE_B`.
I know that the keyword `in` would work the other way around but I can't find an elegant solution without using another loop.

Comment: Are these strings inside the list/set?

Answer (score 1):

Set1 is not a set (like you stated) but a tuple, so you need to cast and then you can use a set intersection to filter duplicates across both

```
 matching_files = list(set(matches).intersection(set(set1)))

 for file in matching_files:
     # Do your copy
     pass
```

Answer (score 0):

what about intersection between sets?and then you copy the result?Not really sure though if you are looking for a math in the string of if the elements in the list are the "same" as the one in the set

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.

```
import re
pat = re.compile('|'.join(set1))
for match in matches:
    if pat.search(match):
        # do stuff
```

But I would probably introduce the filter with the help of regex (or possibly `fnmatch`) while calculating `matches`

Answer (score 0):

use `any` to check if any matches eachfile.

```
matches = ['fooFILE_Aspam.txt', 'barFILE_B.CSV', 'codeFILE_Cdog.vcf']
set1 = ('FILE_A', 'FILE_B', 'FILE_F')

for eachfile in matches:
    if any([x in eachfile for x in set1]):
        print eachfile
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `in` operator applies to both `set` and `str`. In the former case, you are checking for exact string match; in the second, for contiguous substring inclusion. I assume you are after the latter, so this should work.

```
matches = ['fooFILE_Aspam.txt', 'barFILE_B.CSV', 'codeFILE_Cdog.vcf']
set1 = {'FILE_A', 'FILE_B', 'FILE_F'}

to_move = [fname for fname in matches if any(t in fname for t in set1)]

# In [39]: q.to_move
# Out[39]: ['fooFILE_Aspam.txt', 'barFILE_B.CSV']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
for eachfile in [x for x in matches if x in set1]:
    print 'find one match'
    shutil.copy2(eachfile, '/Users/r2-d2/Desktop/folder')
    print 'copy done'
```

Or, do it inside the for loop - list:

```
def shCopy(file,dest='/Users/r2-d2/Desktop/folder'):
    print 'find one match'
    shutil.copy2(file, dest)
    print 'copy done'

[shCopy(x) for x in matches if x in set1]
```